# Can a Raspberry Pi be reconfigured to reboot automatically if the SDcard becomes unreadable?

Tags: ssd, raspberry-pi

I have a Pi out on a hosting environment.  The pi would occasionally become inaccessible, but responsive to pings.

My provider has been kind enough to reboot it a couple times and let me syslog to their syslogd.  It seems like a problem on the SD Card.  First the root filesystem remounts read-only, but then it seems to be unreadable to Apache and sshd afterwards.  I can't ssh in, and I can't execute a cgi to reboot the box.

I would like to set up the pi so that it reboots if the filesystem becomes inaccessible.  Is there a handy trick to do this?  e.g., something in proc which would tell the system to reboot rather than unmount root?

(note: the pi runs for 2-5 days before it locks up like this)

Comment: I'd suggest trying to identify the problem before trying to circumvent it. For example, swap the SD card if possible. If that doesn't work and it only happens if it's running for more than a day, how about rebooting once a day during off-hours? Like a daily maintenance.

Comment: Did you enable any overclocking or power saving? If so, disable it. I've had very bad experiences with that and SD cards.

Comment: No overclocking and it's only a few months in the field.  Swapping the SD Card won't be possible for a few months.  Agreed though, it's the right thing to try.  Just not possible for a while.

Answer (score 2):

It depends a bit also on the state the system is in when this trouble occours (ie. what can be still done and what not with the filesystem in this state).

This being said a classic solution could be to enable the watchdog and then do a small application (can be even a very simple shell script that monitors the "dmesg" or "mount" output for the situation you're seeing) that refreshes it if all seems fine.

I suggested the watchdog instead of a normal call to a manual "reboot" since if the filesystem is in bad state then it may be even impossible to execute parts from the filesystem.

A query to bigG for specific Raspberry PI Watchdog usage gave me [this link](http://vk5tu.livejournal.com/35721.html) which may be very useful for you.